# Detect if user changed inputbox in input form with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to detect when a field is changed. My form fields are generated using ng-repeat.

Assume formfields is as follows: {"FIELD1":"", "FIELD2":"", "FIELD3":"Prepopulated", "FIELD4":""}

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<form name="myform">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, keyvalue) in formfields">
 <input name="{{key}}" ng-model="formfields[key]">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

My problem is, when I try to log with "console.log($scope.myForm.FIELD1)" inside of my checkPristine() function, pristine is always set to true and never changes to false. How can I check to see if fields have changed? Open to alternatives to pristine if it does not work.

Comment: use $dirty on form or field to check changed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an ng-blur directive to the input like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/54r4991j/

### Angular

```
vm.formfields = {"FIELD1":"", "FIELD2":"", "FIELD3":"Prepopulated", "FIELD4":""};
vm.watchFormField = function(fieldKey) {
    alert(fieldKey + 'changed to ' + vm.formfields[fieldKey]);
}
```

### HTML

```
<form name="myform">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, keyvalue) in ctrl.formfields">
        <input name="{{key}}" ng-model="ctrl.formfields[key]" ng-blur="ctrl.watchFormField(key)">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I detect what value it was before change? Say if I had 2 fields changed, I want to know those two fields changed.

Comment: One way to do it is make a copy of your initial form fields and update the originals as the new ones get populated like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m7tv1azr/

Comment: Another option is to broadcast your change and update it accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/qu13cmym/